# Get session after log in with JavaScript SDK on serverside and get the username also

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I am trying to do my first Facebook log in. So I am using the Facebook SDK for JavaScript for implementing the pop up log in and then i want to use the SDK for PHP to store the username in the database ( for displaying in my web app ).

The problem is that this PHP code i am using doesn't get the session after log in by JavaScript pop up and first refresh. It get`s the info after a second refresh.

The second problem is that i cant find a way to get the username from the id.
Username is facebook.com/**john.doe1** and is equivalent with the id facebook.com/**1241245235** .

So right now i am using the [Facebook Login for the Web with the JavaScript SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/v2.1) which is the standard log in with JavaScript.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Facebook Login JavaScript Example</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<script>
  // This is called with the results from from FB.getLoginStatus().
  function statusChangeCallback(response) {
    console.log('statusChangeCallback');
    console.log(response);
    // The response object is returned with a status field that lets the
    // app know the current login status of the person.
    // Full docs on the response object can be found in the documentation
    // for FB.getLoginStatus().
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
      // Logged into your app and Facebook.
      testAPI();
    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
      // The person is logged into Facebook, but not your app.
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
        'into this app.';
    } else {
      // The person is not logged into Facebook, so we're not sure if
      // they are logged into this app or not.
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
        'into Facebook.';
    }
  }

  // This function is called when someone finishes with the Login
  // Button.  See the onlogin handler attached to it in the sample
  // code below.
  function checkLoginState() {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
      statusChangeCallback(response);
    });
  }

  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId      : '{your-app-id}',
    cookie     : true,  // enable cookies to allow the server to access 
                        // the session
    xfbml      : true,  // parse social plugins on this page
    version    : 'v2.1' // use version 2.1
  });

  // Now that we've initialized the JavaScript SDK, we call 
  // FB.getLoginStatus().  This function gets the state of the
  // person visiting this page and can return one of three states to
  // the callback you provide.  They can be:
  //
  // 1. Logged into your app ('connected')
  // 2. Logged into Facebook, but not your app ('not_authorized')
  // 3. Not logged into Facebook and can't tell if they are logged into
  //    your app or not.
  //
  // These three cases are handled in the callback function.

  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    statusChangeCallback(response);
  });

  };

  // Load the SDK asynchronously
  (function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

  // Here we run a very simple test of the Graph API after login is
  // successful.  See statusChangeCallback() for when this call is made.
  function testAPI() {
    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
      console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.name);
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML =
        'Thanks for logging in, ' + response.name + '!';
    });
  }
</script>

<!--
  Below we include the Login Button social plugin. This button uses
  the JavaScript SDK to present a graphical Login button that triggers
  the FB.login() function when clicked.
-->

<fb:login-button scope="public_profile,email" onlogin="checkLoginState();">
</fb:login-button>

<div id="status">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

After I log in I want to pass the information to server side (PHP) so i am using this code:

```
    require_once 'lib/fb/autoload.php';

    use Facebook\FacebookSession;
    use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
    use Facebook\GraphUser;
    use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
    use Facebook\FacebookJavaScriptLoginHelper;

    FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('xxxxx','xxxxx');

    $helper = new FacebookJavaScriptLoginHelper();
    try {
        $session = $helper->getSession();
    } catch(FacebookRequestException $ex) {
        // When Facebook returns an error
    } catch(\Exception $ex) {
        // When validation fails or other local issues
    }

    if($session) {

      try {

        $user_profile = (new FacebookRequest(
          $session, 'GET', '/me'
        ))->execute()->getGraphObject(GraphUser::className());

        echo "Name: " . $user_profile->getName();
        echo '<br>';
        echo "Id: " . $user_profile->getId();
        echo '<br>';
        echo "Link: " . $user_profile->getLink();

      } catch(FacebookRequestException $e) {

        echo "Exception occured, code: " . $e->getCode();
        echo " with message: " . $e->getMessage();

      }   

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `username` field has been deprecated with Graph API v2.0. Have a look at

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0_graph_api

> `/me/username` is no longer available.

Why you switch from frontend to backend is also not really clear to me. I'd recommend that you decide whether you want to use PHP or JavaScript. But nevertheless, you'll not be able to get the `username` anymore.

Comment: I am using the facebook SDK just to get the popup login... I could do that with php also but i get redirected from main page to facebook and then back. I am switching to backend in order to get his web app account info or to register him if he doesn't have an account. So if i am unable to get his username ... i must make the user to create a new username on the web app... Tnx for your answer